# Probability (Methods of Enumeration)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

On a midterm exam there are 7 topics to study. The professor selects 4 at random to
include on the midterm. A student studies only 5 topics. What is the probability that
the two unstudied topics are both on the midterm exam?

I know that the denominator will be 7C4 since there are 7C4 ways the professor can choose 4 topics from 7 topics. I am confused with the numerator?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $7 \choose 4$  ways the prof can choose 4 topics from 7 topics.

If the exam includes the 2 unstudied topics, there are $5\choose 2$ ways for the prof to choose the other 2 topics for the exam from the studied topics.

So the probability that the two unstudied topics appear on the exam is ${5\choose 2}/ {7 \choose 4}=2/7$.